# Jacobian and continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Trying to prove that if $g:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is continuously differentiable then $\det J(g(x))$ is continuous. It seems obvious as $\det J(g(x))$ is a polymnomial consisting of the partial derivatives of $g$ which all are continuous, but I am having troubles proving it explicity. I would like to do with via epsilon delta proof

Comment: All done for you bud

Comment: Note the difference in appearance between $detJ(g(x))$ and $\det J(g(x))$.  The latter uses \det with a backslash. That not only de-italicizes it, but also results in spacing to the left in things like $a\det(M)$ and spacing on both sides in things like $a\det M$.  It is standard usgage. I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: I would prove separate lemmas, one saying that every polynomial in several variables is continuous (hence determinant is a continuous function), and another saying a composition of continuous functions is continuous. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Can one show that $\forall\varepsilon>0\  \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\ \forall j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\ \exists\delta_{ij}$ if $\forall i,j |N_{ij} - M_{ij}|<\delta_{ij}$ then $|\det N - \det M|<\varepsilon$? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the fact that $\det$ is a polynomial in the entries proves what you need. You are probably using the definition that a function is $C^1$ if its partial derivatives are continuous. Hence, defining $\partial: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ as $\partial(x)=(\ldots, \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j},\ldots)$, we see (by hypothesis) that $\partial$ is continuous. Now, it is easy to see that there is a function $\overline{\det
}$ which is a sum of multiplication of projections that yields ${\overline{\det}}\circ \partial=\det(g(x))$. Since sums are continuous, projections are continuous and multiplications are continuous, we get that ${\overline{\det}} \circ \partial$ is continuous, hence so is $\det (g(x))$.

Also, you could argue as follows: a function $f: \mathbb{R
^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$ if the derivative

$$Df: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n) $$
$$ x \mapsto D_xf$$

is continuous. Since $\det : L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and composition of continuous functions is continuous, the result follows. The advantage of this approach is that it is coordinate-free (although you will probably use coordinates to arrive at the fact that $\det$ is continuous).

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by $L(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^n})$?

Comment: It is the space of linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself.

Comment: Thanks, and in particular why $\mathbb{R^{n^2}}$? why squared

Comment: Because I'm ranging $i,j$ in $1 \leq i,j \leq n$. Just look at how much people there is in the jacobian matrix.

Comment: A typesetting oddity: \overline{\det}\circ\partial is rendered like this: $\overline{\det}\circ\partial$, whereas {\overline{\det}}\circ\partial yields this: ${\overline{\det}}\circ\partial$.  The \circ operator behaves like the plus sign: spacing to the left and right in things like $3+5$ but no extra spacing in things like $+5$.  Apparently the \overline{} makes it behave as in $+5$ rather than as in $3+5$.  But I put braces around the \overline{\det} and it treated that like the foregoing $3$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @xboxguy2 : Another bit of standard typesetting usage \mathbb{R}^n versus \mathbb{R^n}: $\mathbb{R}^n$ versus $\mathbb{R^n}$.  There's no reason why the superscript $n$ should be included within \mathbb{}. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy This "typesetting oddity" is indeed an interesting phenomenom. I find the latter much more appealing.

Comment: Should one define $C^1$ to mean more than just that all of the partial derivatives are everywhere continuous?  If $(x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ has both partials equal to $0$ at a point but the directional derivative in the $(1,1)$ direction at that point is not $0$, then $f$ is not normally considered differentiable at that point.  For differentiability there has to be a tangent space.  So for $C^1$, I would think the tangent space has a vary continuously  in $(x,y)$.  (But certainly for _this_ problem, continuity of the partial derivatives is enough.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I don't think that the definition that "$C^n$ iff partial derivatives of order $n$ exist and are continuous is the most natural. The most natural definition, to me, is that "$C^n$ iff the $n$-th derivative is a continuous function". This is directly taken from the definition on the real-valued case. Partial derivatives have some peculiarities when we try to compare them to ordinal derivatives of a real function, so why generalize $C^n$ with a definition that relies on them, instead of a "intrinsic" one? (of course, the definitions are equivalent, but the point of view is quite different).